# TangoWithDjango .bashrc edit causing errors

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, django

I'm currently doing the Tango with Django module and I've edited my .bashrc as it lists.

Appending

```
 [[ -s $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]] && source $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc
```

to the end of it. However now whenever I try to do anything in the terminal it opens with

```
awk: 1: unexpected character '.'
```

followed by, for example,

```
Command 'gedit' is available in '/usr/bin/gedit'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH  environment variable.
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is this question answered or not?

Answer (score 2):

I think you've overwritten your PATH with that source command, which I would say is unnecessary. The easier way to do it is to add a line like this:

```
export PATH=~/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc:$PATH
```

That will add your location to your PATH

To check your path at any time you can do "echo $PATH". I imagine you'll find only one thing there at the moment.